# Convert Unix Time to Date & time without using any library or predefined helpers

Tags: php, datetime, unix

I was asked in an interview question on how to convert a Unix datetime integer to date & time. I was stunned as I have been using libraries and I was only able to convert till the year. For my knowledge, I seek the experts here to help me solve the puzzle that I was not able to do. I used PHP coding mechanism to solve it:

```
 $time = 1471488076; //08/18/2016 @ 2:41am (UTC)

 $SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
 $SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
 $SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60; 

 $s = $time % $SECONDS_IN_DAY;

 $hour = floor($s /  $SECONDS_IN_HOUR); //$hour = 2
 $mins = floor(($s / 60) % 60); //$mins = 41
 $seconds = floor($s % 60); //$seconds = 16

 echo "TIME >> $hours:$mins:$seconds".PHP_EOL; // 2:41:16

 $year = floor(1970 + ($time / $SECONDS_IN_YEAR)); //$year = 2016
```

However I was not able to solve month and day as I was lost. I seek the experts here to advice me on how to solve the month and year. I was not able to go any further. It was a disappointment.

I cannot use  strtotime or any predefined date time class provided by the programming languages. This was the restriction that was given to me. Weird it may sound but that is how tough the interview was.

Comment: st totime? Maybe its a function built into php I wouldn't call that a library?  otherwise you just count the sencods from 1970, but that's not strait forward because of leap years and what not.

Comment: The thing is , I was restricted from using strtotime. Yeas 2016 is a leap year. I just need to know how to solve the month and day without using any given classes by the programming languages.

Comment: um... lol ... date('y-m-d', timestamp )? if you mean by hand, then it's a fools errand and whats the point.

Comment: exactly, that is what I tot so ..... but this was asked as a question.

Comment: you would basically divide the current time by the seconds per year ( 31556926 ), then take the remainder of that and rinse and repeat ( really you would subtract the total seconds of the even year from the total seconds to get the remainder ) then repeat for the months and so on.

Comment: @ ArtisiticPhoenix: Can you quote an example on how is this done?

Comment: It will take me some time, but there are 20832076 seconds left over from getting the year, then how many even months in that.

Comment: I will try based on what you have suggested but if you could answer, it benefits a lot of people. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be an average at best for the month, there are many things to account for that simple math wont work for.  Not all months have the same number of days, you would need an array of months with the number of seconds in each.

Comment: `Month: 7.9` so either end of July or early Augest , `July 28th`

Comment: It will never be correct without accounting for seconds for each month because the best you can do is average the seconds in a month to about `2629743.83`

Comment: FWIW, such questions are usually asked to judge your *approach* to dealing with the problem, rather than the practical implementation. A full implementation accounting for all the oddities including leap seconds, leap years and timezones is very complex, and I wouldn't expect anyone to produce a working version in the span of an interview. The more important aspect of this question likely was exactly that you were expected to recount all these pitfalls, and perhaps come up with a rough pseudocode implementation of the raw number conversion. Or so I would hope…

Comment: @PaulCrovella I suppose UNIX → human time is not that complex in terms of leap seconds, true. The other way around is a bit more brain-bendy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little work to do to account for the variable number of days per month/year, but it's not so bad. The basic idea is to iterate down until there's no more days left on the time stamp.

Handling negative time stamps is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Example:**

```
const SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
const SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
const SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR;

const DAYS_PER_YEAR = 365;
const DAYS_PER_LEAP_YEAR = DAYS_PER_YEAR + 1;

const EPOCH_MONTH = 1;
const EPOCH_YEAR = 1970;

function getDateTime(int $timestamp) : array
{
    $days = intdiv($timestamp, SECONDS_PER_DAY);

    $year = EPOCH_YEAR;
    while ($days >= getDaysForYear($year)) {
        $days -= getDaysForYear($year);
        $year++;
    }

    $daysPerMonth = getDaysPerMonth($year);
    $month = EPOCH_MONTH;
    while ($days >= $daysPerMonth[$month]) {
        $days -= $daysPerMonth[$month];
        $month++;
    }

    $day = $days + 1;

    $secondsRemaining = $timestamp % SECONDS_PER_DAY;
    $hour = intdiv($secondsRemaining, SECONDS_PER_HOUR);
    $minute = intdiv($secondsRemaining, SECONDS_PER_MINUTE) % SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
    $second = $secondsRemaining % SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    return [
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'day' => $day,
        'hour' => $hour,
        'minute' => $minute,
        'second' => $second
    ];
}

function isLeapYear(int $year) : bool
{
    return $year % 400 === 0 || ($year % 4 === 0 && $year % 100 !== 0);
}

function getDaysForYear(int $year) : int {
    return isLeapYear($year) ? DAYS_PER_LEAP_YEAR : DAYS_PER_YEAR;
}

function getDaysPerMonth(int $year) : array
{
    return [0, 31, isLeapYear($year) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
}


$time = 1471488076; //08/18/2016 @ 2:41am (UTC)
print_r(getDateTime($time));
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2016
    [month] => 8
    [day] => 18
    [hour] => 2
    [minute] => 41
    [second] => 16
)
```

Which you can take and format as you please.

---

[Online demo.](https://3v4l.org/oDLh2#v700)

Answer (score 0):

For example ( this will get you an approximation ) by finding the whole unit, using the remainder in the next set to find that whole unit.  Each time reducing the number of seconds to what the remainder is.

```
$time = 1471488076; //08/18/2016 @ 2:41am (UTC)

$SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$SECONDS_IN_MONTH = $SECONDS_IN_YEAR / 12;
$SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
$SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60;

$num = floor($time / $SECONDS_IN_YEAR);
echo "\nYears: ".$num . "\n";
$remainingSeconds = $time - ($num * $SECONDS_IN_YEAR);
echo "\nremainder: ".$remainingSeconds . "\n";

$year = 1970 + $num;

$num = floor( $remainingSeconds / $SECONDS_IN_MONTH);
echo "\nMonth: ".$num . "\n";
$remainingSeconds = $remainingSeconds - ($num * $SECONDS_IN_MONTH);
echo "\nremainder: ".$remainingSeconds . "\n";

$month = $num;

$num = floor( $remainingSeconds / $SECONDS_IN_DAY);
echo "\nDay: ".$num . "\n";
$remainingSeconds = $remainingSeconds - ($num * $SECONDS_IN_DAY);
echo "\nremainder: ".$remainingSeconds . "\n";

$day = $num;

$num = floor( $remainingSeconds / $SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
echo "\nHour: ".$num . "\n";
$remainingSeconds = $remainingSeconds - ($num * $SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
echo "\nremainder: ".$remainingSeconds . "\n";

$hour = $num;

$num = floor( $remainingSeconds / 60);
echo "\nMinute: ".$num . "\n";
$remainingSeconds = $remainingSeconds - ($num * 60);
 echo "\nremainder: ".$remainingSeconds . "\n";

 $min = $num;

 $sec = floor($remainingSeconds);

 echo $month."/".$day."/".$year." ".$hour.":".$min.":".$sec;
```

Outputs

```
Years: 46
remainder: 20832076

Month: 7
remainder: 2436076

Day: 28
remainder: 16876

Hour: 4
remainder: 2476

Minute: 41
remainder: 16

7/28/2016 4:41:16
```

But as I stated with the average seconds per month it will never be correct, you would need something like an array with the amount of seconds per month you could subtract down through the array in a loop until you go negative, then its the month before that one.  Then you would sum those seconds up, and what is left is the hours minutes and seconds.

Basically reduce each one once you go over the even unit..

Without that it's just an approximation at best.  Even given that it wont account for leap years.

There are probably much better ways to do this, but that just jumps out as the easiest way to get a rough figure.

Comment: I think approximation is just fine. Let me look at this and mark it as anwered soon.

Comment: The answer that I get is this `7/28/2016 1:17:49`

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 pieces of code in c++, but with some minor adjustments it can work in other languages as well. I also focussed on optimising it for speed and spend the whole day checking the code and testing it with various solutions to make it faster.

One piece is complete and works with:

1. Negative inputs.
2. time before common era (BCE).
3. 400 year leap cycle rule.
4. 100 year leapless cycle rule.
5. 4 year leap cycle rule.

the other piece, is basically the same as the first.
But I ditched the 400, 100, and BCE rules to optimise it for speed.
It works from: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 till 2100-02-28 23:59:59.

Enjoy!

```
/*
disclaimer about leap seconds:
unix seconds actually differ from real seconds.
this means there are always either 31,536,000 seconds or 31,622,400 seconds in an unix year/unix leap year.
therefore the unix second is ever so slightly slower than a real second.
fortunately for us, this keeps unix time synchronised with real time without the hussle of dealing with leap seconds (Hurray! *insert party hat*).

Anyway, to determine the year, month, monthday, weekday, hour, minute and second, we use the following approach:

1.  create a new epoch based on the unixepoch where the new epoch is always before the unixtime. (to make it work with negative inputs.)
    note: this adjusted epoch is always on a date where the 400, 100, 4, and 1 year cycles all repeat. Examples: 1601-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-01 00:00:00, etc.

2.  calculate how many days have passed since this new epoch.
3.  calculate how many 146097 days (400 year cycle including 97 leap days) fit inside it and subtract to create a remainder.
4.  calculate how many 365024 days (100 year cycle including 24 leap days) fit inside the remainder and subtract to create the second remainder.
5.  calculate how many 1461 days (4 year cycle including 1 leap day) fit inside the second remainder and subtract to create the third remainder.
6.  calculate how many 365 days (1 year cycle) fit inside the third remainder to create the final remainder.
    what you are left with is total amount of cycles of each cycle length, and the days that have passed this year.

7.  now add the 400, 100, 4, and 1 year cycles multiplied by their respective year lengths together to get the years that passed since the new epoch.
8.  and add them to this new epoch to get the current year.
9.  check whether the year is smaller than 1 (before common era) and subtract an additional year from the final date to correct for it.
10. now to calculate the month and monthday, check whether the year is a leapyear.
11. if it's leap, we use 1 method, if it's not, we use the other.
12. use the remainder to calculate the current hour.
13. use the remainder to calculate the current minute.
14. use the remainder to calculate the current second.
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std; //so you dont have to type std:: every darn time.
    
long long int unixTS1 = 0;  //the amount of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, (using long long int so it also works for outdated compilers)?
long long int unixTS2 = 0;  //adjusted timestamp.
int fits = 0;               //necessary to calculate the new epoch.
int days = 0;               //days that passed since adjusted epoch.
int hms = 0;                //remaining hours minutes and seconds (hms) in seconds after subtracting the days in seconds that passed.
int newepoch = 2001;        //in order to make the code work with negative inputs.
int y400 = 0;               //400 year cycle repeats.
int r400 = 0;               //remaining days after the 400 year cycles.
int y100 = 0;               //100 year cycle repeats.
int r100 = 0;               //remaining days after the 100 year cycles.
int y4 = 0;                 //4 year cycle repeats.
int r4 = 0;                 //remaining days after the 4 year cycles.
int y1 = 0;                 //1 year cycle repeats.
int r1 = 0;                 //remaining days after the 1 year cycles.

int year = 0;               //actual year.
int yearday = 0;            //day of the year       (1 to 366)
int month = 0;              //month of the year     (1 to 12)
int monthday = 0;           //day of the month      (1 to 31)
int weekday = 0;            //day of the week       (1 to 7)
int hour = 0;               //hour of the day       (0 to 23)
int minute = 0;             //minute of the hour    (0 to 59)
int second = 0;             //second of the minute  (0 to 59)

int unixdate() //1,000,000,000 repeats on intel i7-7700k = approximately 23 seconds.
{
        unixTS2 = unixTS1 - 978307200; //time in seconds since 2001-01-01 00:00:00. (new epoch).
        
        if(unixTS2 < 0) //we need a positive timestamp to make the code work, if it's negative, we create a new epoch to make it positive.
        {
            fits = (unixTS2 / 12622780800) + 1; //calculating how many 400 year cycles fit inside the negative timestamp.
            newepoch = 2001 - fits * 400; //subtracting the 400 year cycles from the epoch to create a new one.
            unixTS2 += fits * 12622780800; //adding the 400 year cycles to the timestamp to make it positive.
        }
        else{newepoch = 2001;}
        
        /*
        to calculate the remainder I don't use the modulus operator (%) because subtracting an already calculated value is faster, with the exception of the long long int variable.
        I do not know why this is, but tests reveal a significant speed difference.
        I suspect conversion necesseties from the native variables of my CPU but let it be known if you found the reason, cheers.
        */
        
        days = unixTS2 / 86400;
        hms = unixTS2 % 86400;
        
        hour = hms / 3600;
        minute = (hms - hour * 3600) / 60;
        second = (hms - hour * 3600) - minute * 60;
        
        y400 = days / 146097;
        r400 = days - 146097 * y400;
        y100 = r400 / 36524;
        r100 = r400 - 36524 * y100;
        y4 = r100 / 1461;
        r4 = r100 - 1461 * y4;
        y1 = r4 / 365;
        r1 = r4 - 365 * y1;
        yearday = r1 + 1;
        weekday = r400 % 7 + 1;
        
        if(y100 > 3) //special occasion that happens at the last day in the 400 year cycle.
        {
            year = newepoch + y100 * 100 - 1;
            yearday = 366;
            month = 12;
            monthday = 31;
        }
        else
        {
            if(y1 > 3) //special occasion that happens at the last day in the 4 year cycle.
            {
                year = newepoch + y400 * 400 + y100 * 100 + y4 * 4 + y1 - 1;
                yearday = 366;
                month = 12;
                monthday = 31;
            }
            else
            {
                year = newepoch + y400 * 400 + y100 * 100 + y4 * 4 + y1;
                /*
                now we need to select the month.
                I created and tested 3 types of ways to get to the correct month.
                1.  option 1 involves directly calculating the month with a relative simple formula with 2 subtractive checks.
                    worked for every day of the year including leap years but even after careful optimisation was still about 60% slower than option 3.
                2.  option 2 involves a single division calculation to approximate the month with a minimum.
                    followed by checking the month after and choosing either depending on the result. this was quite memory intensive, but still faster than option 1.
                3.  the third and best option I could come up with involves little calculation at all, and uses just 4 to 5 subtractive comparisons to get the right month and monthday.
                    the first 2 check gets you down to 4 possible months, another check to 2, and the final check to 1.
                    it seems a bit messy though, but I tried to make it compact and still readable in 1 overview, so enjoy.
                */
                if(y1 > 2 && (y4 < 24 || y100 > 2)) //if leap, select month and calculate monthday.
                {
                    if(r1 > 243)                    {if(r1 > 304)   {if(r1 > 334)   {month = 12;monthday = r1 - 334;}
                                                                    else            {month = 11;monthday = r1 - 304;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 273)   {month = 10;monthday = r1 - 273;}
                                                                    else            {month = 9;monthday = r1 - 243;}}}
                    else            {if(r1 > 120)   {if(r1 > 181)   {if(r1 > 212)   {month = 8;monthday = r1 - 212;}
                                                                    else            {month = 7;monthday = r1 - 181;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 151)   {month = 6;monthday = r1 - 151;}
                                                                    else            {month = 5;monthday = r1 - 120;}}}
                                    else            {if(r1 > 59)    {if(r1 > 90)    {month = 4;monthday = r1 - 90;}
                                                                    else            {month = 3;monthday = r1 - 59;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 30)    {month = 2;monthday = r1 - 30;}
                                                                    else            {month = 1;monthday = r1 + 1;}}}}
                }
                else
                {
                    if(r1 > 242)                    {if(r1 > 303)   {if(r1 > 333)   {month = 12;monthday = r1 - 333;}
                                                                    else            {month = 11;monthday = r1 - 303;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 272)   {month = 10;monthday = r1 - 272;}
                                                                    else            {month = 9;monthday = r1 - 242;}}}
                    else            {if(r1 > 119)   {if(r1 > 180)   {if(r1 > 211)   {month = 8;monthday = r1 - 211;}
                                                                    else            {month = 7;monthday = r1 - 180;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 150)   {month = 6;monthday = r1 - 150;}
                                                                    else            {month = 5;monthday = r1 - 119;}}}
                                    else            {if(r1 > 58)    {if(r1 > 89)    {month = 4;monthday = r1 - 89;}
                                                                    else            {month = 3;monthday = r1 - 58;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 30)    {month = 2;monthday = r1 - 30;}
                                                                    else            {month = 1;monthday = r1 + 1;}}}}
                }
            }
        }
        // and finally.
        if(year < 1){year--;} //this one line accounts for years before common era (BCE) because there is no year 0 apparently.
    return 0;
}

/*
however, one might not care about accuracy far in the past and future and simply needs a simple and fast piece of code.
so by ditching some rules we can make the code 110% faster and still make it work from:
1970-01-01 00:00:00 till:
2100-02-28 23:59:59.
*/

int unixdatefast() //1,000,000,000 repeats on intel i7-7700k = approximately 11 seconds.
{
        days = unixTS1 / 86400;
        hms = unixTS1 % 86400;
        hour = hms / 3600;
        minute = (hms - hour * 3600) / 60;
        second = (hms - hour * 3600) - minute * 60;
        
        y4 = days / 1461;
        r4 = days - 1461 * y4;
        y1 = r4 / 365;
        r1 = r4 - 365 * y1;
        
        weekday = days % 7 + 3;
        yearday = r1 + 1;
        
            if(y1 > 3)
            {
                year = 1972 + y4 * 4;
                yearday = 366;
                month = 12;
                monthday = 31;
            }
            else
            {   
                year = 1969 + y4 * 4 + y1;          
                if(y1 > 2)
                {
                    if(r1 > 243)                    {if(r1 > 304)   {if(r1 > 334)   {month = 12;monthday = r1 - 334;}
                                                                    else            {month = 11;monthday = r1 - 304;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 273)   {month = 10;monthday = r1 - 273;}
                                                                    else            {month = 9;monthday = r1 - 243;}}}
                    else            {if(r1 > 120)   {if(r1 > 181)   {if(r1 > 212)   {month = 8;monthday = r1 - 212;}
                                                                    else            {month = 7;monthday = r1 - 181;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 151)   {month = 6;monthday = r1 - 151;}
                                                                    else            {month = 5;monthday = r1 - 120;}}}
                                    else            {if(r1 > 59)    {if(r1 > 90)    {month = 4;monthday = r1 - 90;}
                                                                    else            {month = 3;monthday = r1 - 59;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 30)    {month = 2;monthday = r1 - 30;}
                                                                    else            {month = 1;monthday = r1 + 1;}}}}
                }
                else
                {
                    if(r1 > 242)                    {if(r1 > 303)   {if(r1 > 333)   {month = 12;monthday = r1 - 333;}
                                                                    else            {month = 11;monthday = r1 - 303;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 272)   {month = 10;monthday = r1 - 272;}
                                                                    else            {month = 9;monthday = r1 - 242;}}}
                    else            {if(r1 > 119)   {if(r1 > 180)   {if(r1 > 211)   {month = 8;monthday = r1 - 211;}
                                                                    else            {month = 7;monthday = r1 - 180;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 150)   {month = 6;monthday = r1 - 150;}
                                                                    else            {month = 5;monthday = r1 - 119;}}}
                                    else            {if(r1 > 58)    {if(r1 > 89)    {month = 4;monthday = r1 - 89;}
                                                                    else            {month = 3;monthday = r1 - 58;}}
                                                    else            {if(r1 > 30)    {month = 2;monthday = r1 - 30;}
                                                                    else            {month = 1;monthday = r1 + 1;}}}}
                }
            }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    unixdate();
    //unixdatefast();

    cout << "unixTS1: "         << unixTS1      << endl;
    cout << "unixTS2: "         << unixTS2      << endl;    
    cout << "Fits: "            << fits         << endl;
    cout << "newepoch: "        << newepoch     << endl;
    cout << "days: "            << days         << endl;
    cout << "hms: "             << hms          << endl << endl;

    cout << "y400: "            << y400         << endl;
    cout << "r400: "            << r400         << endl;
    cout << "y100: "            << y100         << endl;
    cout << "r100: "            << r100         << endl;
    cout << "y4: "              << y4           << endl;
    cout << "r4: "              << r4           << endl;
    cout << "y1: "              << y1           << endl;
    cout << "r1: "              << r1           << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Weekday: "         << weekday      << endl << endl;    
    
    cout << "Date: "            << year << "-" << month << "-" << monthday << " " << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << endl;
    cout << "Yearday: "         << yearday      << endl;
    return 0;
}
```